# Question objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags

Tags: django, django-views

i am trying to save both FK data as well as tags into same model. FK is the user. user has to submit the question and tags like stack overflow. but i am not able to save both of them. it looks some issue at my views. Can you please help.

ValueError at /qanda/askquestion/
    Question objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags.
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/qanda/askquestion/
    Django Version: 2.2.4
    Exception Type: ValueError
    Exception Value:
    Question objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags.
    Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/taggit/managers.py in **get**, line 424
    Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
    Python Version: 3.7.4
    Python Path:
    ['/Users/SRIRAMAPADMAPRABHA/Desktop/IampythonDEV/iampython',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
     '/Users/SRIRAMAPADMAPRABHA/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

```
Models.py 

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question_category=models.ForeignKey(Question_Category,related_name='questioncategory',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    question_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=250)
    question_description=RichTextField()
    question_tags = TaggableManager()
    question_posted_at=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    question_status= models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
    question_updated_on= models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_title


views.py 

@login_required
def createQuestion(request):   
   if request.method  == 'POST':
      form = QuestionAskForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
              new_question=form.save(commit=False)
              question_title = request.POST['question_title']
              new_question.slug = slugify(new_question.question_title)
              new_question=request.user
              new_question.save()
              form.save_m2m()
              messages.success(request,'You question is succesfully submitted to the forum')
              return redirect('feed')
   else:
        form = QuestionAskForm()

   return render(request,'qanda/askyourquestion.html',{'form':form})
```

I want to submit both foreign key and as well as tag to the database. I am not able to do the tags. Please let me know your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing:

```
    new_question=request.user
```

now `new_question` is no longer a `Question` object, but it is simply the `User` object you use. You should edit the `new_question.user` object instead. For example with:

```
@login_required
def createQuestion(request):   
    if request.method  == 'POST':
        form = QuestionAskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.slug = slugify(form.instance.question_title)
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'You question is succesfully submitted to the forum')
            return redirect('feed')
    else:
        form = QuestionAskForm()
   return render(request,'qanda/askyourquestion.html',{'form':form})
```

By using `form.instance` before saving the form, you prevent having to do the saving process yourself (saving the object *and* the many-to-many relations).

> **Note**: Normally model fields have no prefix with the name of the model. This makes
>   queries longer to read, and often want uses inheritance of (abstract) models to
>   inherit fields, so using a prefix would make it less reusable. Therefore it
>   might be better to rename your field <s>`question_title`</s> to `title`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have changed the form.instance.slug = slugify(form.instance.question_title) to form.instance.question_slug = slugify(form.instance.question_title), after that i am able to save all the fields. And also thanks for suggesting reaming field names.